# How to decide on the significance level,R

Tags: r, significance

I have a quantile regression analysis using panel data. I created significance stars with my own code as seen below

```
starPrinter <- function(pVal) {
  if(pVal < 0.01) {
    return("***")
    }
  if(pVal < 0.05) {
    return("**")
    }
  if(pVal < 0.1) {
    return("*")
    }####################


 else {return("")
    }
    }
```

The significance level is determined based on P-values. However, in the regression results, according to P-values, some variables look insignificant even though t-values are high.Why is the case? What do you think I should do?

Please see [Regression Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDY2J.png) where for ex. x7 variable at Q75 should have had one star.(Values in parentheses are t-values)

Comment: Why x7 variable at Q75 should have one star? how did you calculate it?

Comment: @Soheil t-value is above 1.65 so it should have one star. It is calculated in the program itself.

Comment: How many degrees of freedom do you?  The critical values for the t test depend on the df.  For low df the critical values can be quiet large.  See http://hs-biology-ib11.ism-online.org/files/2012/09/t-test-dist.jpeg

Comment: FYI Also your table is a bit weird.  Providing the test statistic in parenthesis is not a convention that I'm use to.  In my experience tables will contain standard errors or even confidence intervals in parenthesis

Comment: @JacobH I built my own code to create table so values in parentheses are t-values. For your first question, it is a panel data and a quantile regression analysis so I am not sure how to compute degrees of freedom. The data have cross sectionally 50 classes, and time series 78 quarters so in total 3949 observations. I use 7 variables in the regression.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not to familiar with QR within a panel framework.  However, a quick googling leads me to believe that inference for QR is a bit different.  This make senses to me insofar as we are trying to perform inference on percentile rather than means (i.e. the usual OLS case).  This might help:  http://www.math.pku.edu.cn/teachers/xirb/Courses/QR2013/QR_6.pdf

Comment: Consequently I suspect your results are correct.  However, make sure you read up on both QR and Panel.  Given the periodicity of your data you may would to look into IV techniques to correct bias (that is assuming you're not using this model for prediction). Arellano and Bond is a good starting point.

Comment: @JacobH what do you mean by you suspect about my results?

Comment: I suspect that the test statistics and critical values produced by the program you ran are correct.  Take a look at slide 15 here http://fmwww.bc.edu/EC-C/S2013/823/EC823.S2013.nn04.slides.pdf.